# Bootstrap card-deck elements not getting the same proportions

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'm displaying card decks in order to show a set of articles stored in a database. This is the pretty simple piece of code I'm using:

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="card-deck">
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{articles}}" as="article">
            <div class="col-12 col-md-4 mb-md-5">
                <div
                    class="card"
                    on-tap="showViewer"
                    data-id$="[[article.id]]"
                >
                    <img
                        class="card-img-top img-fluid vertical-image"
                        src$="{{getArticleImage(article)}}"
                        onerror$="this.src='{{defaultimage}}'"
                        alt="{{getArticleDescription(article)}}"
                    />
                    <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column justify-content-center py-2">
                        <div class="d-flex justify-content-start align-items-center mb-2">
                            <img class="icon-sm mr-2 img-fluid" src={{getFavIcon(article)}}>
                            <span class="medium-text">
                                {{getSources(article)}}
                            </span>
                        </div>
                        <p class="card-text primary-headline medium-text">
                            {{article.schema:headline}}
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </template>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.vertical-image {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: center;
}

.icon-sm {
    height: 20px;
    width: auto;
}

.medium-text {
    font-family: Raleway-Medium;
}

.primary-headline {
    font-size: 25px;
    line-height: 25px;
    text-align: justify;
}
```

According to [Bootstrap documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/card/#card-decks), using the `card-deck` class should make all the cards in the deck to have equal width and height. However, I'm not acheiving that behaviour. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RY0ti.jpg) you are a picture where you can see what I am getting.

What would be the correct way to achieve that all the images in the cards and all the cards have the same height and width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this. Hope it helps.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4 py-2">
            <div class="card card-body h-100">
                Card. I'm just a simple card-block.
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 py-2">
            <div class="card h-100 text-white bg-danger">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h3 class="card-title">Danger</h3>
                    <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-light">Outline</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 py-2">
            <div class="card h-100 card-body">
                Card. I'm just a simple card-block, but I have a little more text!
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 py-2">
            <div class="card h-100 border-primary">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h3 class="card-title">Primary</h3>
                    <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Outline</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 py-2">
            <div class="card h-100 card-body">
                Card. I'm just a simple card-block.
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 py-2">
            <div class="card text-white bg-primary">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h3 class="card-title">Hello</h3>
                    <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-light">Outline</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Adding `h-100` to each card solved the problem of them having different sizes. However, the image inside each card still have different sizes. How could I achieve they all have the same size? I don't know what dimmensions they will have since I'm scrapping the articles from the internet

Comment: if you resize the original image height by CSS they will be squished. Either you have to make same height  by photoshop or leave as it is. Your grids will be all equalheight. So don't have to worry about the grid height.

Comment: It doesn't matter. I just need that all the images have the same height and width. I'm fine with cutting off top or bottom of the image, that's why I set the property `object-fit: cover`, but I'm not getting the results I was expecting. Do you know how could I make the images to all have the same size, cutting off the sides or the top/bottom of the image depending of what is needed?

Comment: You need to add a height of your container div of the images in order to `` object-fit:cover `` to work.